# NOT doesn't work in node/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I basically just want to toggle something between true and false.

```
var currentvalue = doc.findOne({ _id : req.params.the_id });
var opposite = !currentvalue.somethingTrue;
console.log("will this work?? " + opposite);
doc.update({ _id : req.params.the_id }, { $set : { somethingTrue : opposite }})
```

the console always logs true. it just doesn't work.
in the world of node and mongoose, should I do this different?

Also, is it possible now to just enter an expression in mongodb/mongoose, instead of having a workaround like this?(which doesn't even work :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `opposite` will always be `true` because `currentvalue.somethingTrue` will always be `undefined`, which is a "*falsy*" value in JavaScript:

```
console.log( currentvalue.somethingTrue );  // undefined
console.log( !currentvalue.somethingTrue ); // true
```

And, it's `undefined` because the object returned from [`.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) is a [`Query` instance](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) rather than the document being retrieved from the database.

`.findOne()` also acts asynchronously (without blocking surrounding code from continuing), so for it to provide the document, it expects a `callback` function that it can invoke when the document has become available (or an `err` has occurred):

```
doc.findOne({ _id : req.params.the_id }, function (err, currentvalue) {
    var opposite = !currentvalue.somethingTrue;
    // etc.
});
```